# Error: write /proc/60/uid_map: operation not permitted

Tags: gitlab, openshift, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm new to the OpenShift 4.12 world. I try to work with GitLabCI in OpenShift but unfortunately every time I run my pipeline I receive this error:

> cannot write uid_map: write /proc/60/uid_map: operation not permitted

OR

> error writing "0 0 4294967295\n" to /proc/64/uid_map: write /proc/64/uid_map: operation not permitted

I already gave User and Service account  permission to the GitLab runner.
Can somebody help me?

Comment: we had a similar issue trying to get rootless builds working inside of openshift. you will most likely need to adapt the scc used by the serviceaccount that is running the build inside of openshift (or create a new one). in order to set the flag for uid/gid in user namespace the scc needs to have "privileged: true" set.